# Windows 7 randomly umounts and mounts external HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have bought a USB 3.0 SuperSpeed SATA 2.5'' enclosure to connect the HD extracted from my old laptop to the new one.I have tested it and succesfully used it for transfering files (for example a 17 GB movie recently).I also use it with my Raspberry Pi without any problems.

However, when I'm playing some media file from it, sometimes I will hear the sound Windows plays when the drive is disconnected and see that it has disappeared from "Computer", only to hear the sound again a few seconds later and see it appear again.
The problem hasn't ocurred so far using it via USB 2.0, but seems to be pretty random, it may happen a few times while playing the same file, or may not happen at all.
There weren't any issues either when I tried it on the USB 3.0 port of my classroom computer.

Also, the first time this happened I was greeted with multiple windows saying "Please format drive X: to use it".I have checked the logs and it seems that (not always) when it happens an event 51 is registered, which is supposed to be about paging but doesn't apply in this case, so it's supposed to be a sort of general I/O error.

Comment: have you checked the cable? I've noticed many a USB cable developing shorts after long periods of deployment, so if it gets jiggled, the device will lose and regain contact with the device.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the world of USB3. This drove me crazy - and still does - The only solution I came up with it to use a short USB3 cable. The one that came with my WD 2TB drive is about 18". A 3' one gives me trouble.
USB3 is rather sensitive to noise.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you update the USB 3.0 Hub controller driver from the motherboard/computer manufacturer's website manually, @DaRk_St0rM. It's possible that this is causing you the issues. It could also be a faulty USB 3.0 port, so if you have another one on the computer/laptop, I'd try plugging it there instead. Since it's properly working in the USB 2.0 port and on other systems, it's unlikely that the issue is with the drive itself or the enclosure.

Keep us posted with the troubleshooting. Hope this helps you! :)